# How to retrieve historical EOS supply?

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, table, database

I know `$ cleos get currency stats eosio.token EOS` reports the current supply in the blockchain, but how can I get the supply through time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can listen to the block with the issue event of eosio.token, only the issue action can update the supply.

Comment: But would this capture decrease of supply from mechanisms such as RAM fees which burn EOS?

Comment: ram fee doesn't burn now, it maybe used by the community, there's no method to burn the token in eos.token

Comment: you're right, it seems like [it transfers to `N(eosio.ramfee)`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/d7a6fd10ac0ab34595068f339f8b3d24a06f1db3/contracts/eosio.system/delegate_bandwidth.cpp#L197-L200) when selling ram, so to calculate circulating supply maybe i can deduct `get_balance("eosio.ramfee") + get_balance("eosio.stake") + get_balance("eosio.ram")`